# httpd.exe Entry point not found

Tags: php, xampp, apache

I needed to upgrade my local PHP version so I backed up my `htdocs` folder, reinstalled XAMPP using the windows installer and copied back my backup.

I tried running the apache module to be greeted with path warnings. So I then went through every instance of "`/xampp/`" and changed it to "`/Utilities/server/`" in `httpd.conf` and `httpd-xampp.conf` which is very annoying since I've never had to do this before.

Now I get the error:

> The procedure entry point php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll

The `.conf` files are very long so I won't post them here unless someone specifically asks for them.

Comment: what os ? , better try  one more re installation

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. I expect I'll have to do another install if no one has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that A dynamic link library basically associates a dll file with a location. In your instance the location has changed, re-installing php (or xampp) should fix your problem.

Another solution is to check your PHP.INI file for references to any .dll file and make sure the references are correct to your new install folder.